# .NET Core API -> Updating an object also update previously loaded object

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I have implemented a system to log every create/update/delete actions on all controllers.
Basically, the idea is simple as when I update an object in the Update controller, I first do a Get then Update so I have access to original object and updated object as follow.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromRoute] Guid groupId, [FromRoute] Guid licenseId, [FromBody] UpdateLicenseRequest request)
    {
        var cLicense = await _licenseService.GetAsync(groupId, licenseId);

        if (cLicense == null)
            return BadRequest(_localizer["LicenseNotExist"]);

        var uLicense = await _licenseService.UpdateAsync(cLicense, _mapper.Map<License>(request));

        if (uLicense == null)
            return BadRequest();

        await _auditService.CreateAsync(AuditTypeEnum.SVAULT_LICENSE_UPDATE, cLicense, uLicense);

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<LicenseResponse>(uLicense));
    }
```

Here is the detail of the GetAsync method :

```
public async Task<License> GetAsync(Guid groupId, Guid licenseId)
    {
        RSUser cRSUser = await _cloudService.GetCloudAsync(groupId);

        var rxLicense = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return cRSUser.getLicense(licenseId.ToString());
        });

        List<LicenseState> lstStates = await _context.LicenseStates.ToListAsync();
        List<LicenseType> lstTypes = await _context.LicenseTypes.ToListAsync();
        List<LicenseStatus> lstStatus = await _context.LicenseStatus.ToListAsync();
        List<LicenseProduct> lstProducts = await _context.LicenseProducts.ToListAsync();
        Dictionary<string, Group> dcGroups = _context.GroupProperties.AsNoTracking().Where(w => w.Name == GroupProperties.community_id.ToString() && (w.Value == rxLicense.P_community_id || w.Value == rxLicense.P_community_customer_id || w.Value == rxLicense.P_community_reseller_id)).Include(w => w.Group).ToDictionary(w => w.Value, w => w.Group);

        if (rxLicense == null)
            return null;

        return License.ToObject(rxLicense, dcGroups, lstStates, lstTypes, lstStatus, lstProducts);
    }
```

Also find the detail of the Update method :

```
public async Task<License> UpdateAsync(License cLicense, License nLicense)
    {
        RSUser cRSUser = await _cloudService.GetCloudAsync(cLicense.Group.Id);

        var result = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            cLicense.TypeId = nLicense.TypeId;
            cLicense.DataLimit = nLicense.DataLimit;
            cLicense.Email = nLicense.Email;
            cLicense.Notes = nLicense.Notes;

            if (cLicense.TypeId == 8)
                cLicense.DataLimit = 0;

            return cRSUser.updateLicense(cLicense.ToRSUserClass(), new List<RX_licensemode>() { new RX_licensemode() { P_id = nLicense.ProductId.ToString().ToUpper() } }); ;
        });

        if (result != RSC_errorcode.success)
            return null;

        return await GetAsync(cLicense.Group.Id, cLicense.Id);
    }
```

When I do debug and make a stop on cLicense, I see that this object is the current License (which is what I want) but as soon as the UpdateAsync method runs, cLicense is also updated while I want it to remain as the original object.

Does anyone has already had same behavior ? I'm sure this is a normal process but I don't know how to have it working as I wish.

Feel free to ask if anything is not clear enough.
Regards,

Comment: Within your `UpdateAsync` method you have calls like `cLicense.TypeId = nLicense.TypeId`. This sets the values in your current license to the values of the new license.

Comment: @Oliver Yeah, I did not even realize that xD, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Oliver Would you suggest any good ways to achieve the desired behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `cLicense` to `UpdateAsync`, you aren't passing a copy, you are passing THE `cLicence`.  In `UpdateAsync` you are setting the properties of `cLicense` to the values of `nLicense`, which is why you are seeing the values change.

Comment: `In C# all objects are references`. This is simply not correct. C# is a pass-by-value language, which is why the `ref` keyword exists for cases where we want to pass by reference.

Comment: `ref` is *not* required by class objects, but it is required by native value objects (int, long etc).

Comment: @Oliver You are right, I did not even realized, thanks a lot !
Do you have any idea how could I achieve what I want ? Any ways I can copy the complete object (without building an class specific method) ?